# Git How to push repo that consist another repo inside?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository. I needed to add another folder that consist some code files. And it is a git repository too.

```
  TopFolder
     File1.cpp
     File2.cpp
     .git
     InnerFolder
         File.cpp
         .git
```

I added the other code folder to my **TopFolder**, but when i pushed my repo and pull it from another pc, there was an **InnerFolder** but it was empty. Git promted to me to add it as submodule(which i dont know what it is) when i commited, after i tried it but it gave me

> fatal: 'InnerFolder' already exists in the index

Now what should i do? Sımplest way looks like deleting .git in InnerFolder. If there is more sensible way, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably run `git add proxy`, which has then hinted you to run `git submodule add <url> proxy`.

The hint also suggested:

> If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the index with:
> `git rm --cached proxy`

So just use this `git rm` command to remove `proxy` folder from the index (for me, `git rm -f --cached proxy` worked). Then you can run `git submodule add` without errors.

You can also consider using [Git subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree) instead of Git submodules.